# Symantec Mail Security 8240 OS

Tags: symantec

What's the operating system and version on a Symantec Mail Security 8240 appliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Implementation Guide](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/products/sym_mail_security/8200_8300_series/manuals/8200_Series_implementation_guide.pdf), "Symantec Mail Security 8200 Series appliances use the Linux kernel 2.6.7."

I would imagine it's a custom distribution, but I don't know which one it's based on.

Comment: Dennis, I think you're right. Indeed, the only info Symantec gives is that: the Linux kernel version. On it they're surely built a Symantec-custom distrubution for appliances 8200 series. Thank you :)